# Make Excel select cell when clicked if previously selected cell had validation dropdown list displayed

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2007, excel-2010

If the user is on a cell in Excel, and that cell has a data validation dropdown list, and the user has the list displayed:

If the user then clicks on another cell, that other cell is not selected. Instead, all that happens is that the first cell's data validation dropdown list is dismissed. The first cell is still selected, until the user clicks on the second cell again.

Is there any way in VBA to detect when that happens, and select the second cell so the user doesn't have to click a second time?

I'm on Excel 2007.

Comment: user can press esc button before clicking on the other cell.

Answer (score 0):

You could get the behavior you want by using a ComboBox fit into the cell and use that instead of the built-in data validation.  You just lock the cells and have a ComboBox appear in the cells in that column that they select.  If they choose another cell the combobox simply goes invisible.  This also solves the problem of using a custom font (if you have a font with special symbols, for example.)